# How to make system call from another system call in kernel space

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

I am new in Linux kernel development. I have implemented a system call say my_pid in linux kernel 2.6. I want to call getpid system call from my system call. How can I do it?

I want something like:

> pid_t my_pid(){
>       return getpid(); }

Also from C in user-space I can call any system call using: syscall(); What is the generic way to do this in kernel mode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There *is* no generic way of doing this.

If you are in kernel space, you should invoke kernel functions that implement the system call functionality *directly* instead of using `syscall`-type instructions, or use other means of extracting the desired information / affecting the desired action.

For the specific case of `getpid()`, you can simply use `current->pid`.

The kernel name `current` is always a pointer to the current `task_struct`, which is defined via [`<linux/sched.h>`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=include/linux/sched.h) (search for `struct task_struct`). Code that accesses members of that usually gets inlined, i.e. there's not even a function call (and much less a system call) required to get these when your code is running as part of the kernel.