# testing negative or failure cases in system call implementation

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

This is my lab assignment: I am a beginner in kernel space.

I did a simple system call implementation and it works as expected. But, I wanted to go a level further and look into giving incorrect data to my system call and see if it handles it.

For eg., I used access_ok in my system call. I really want to pass a invalid user space pointer and see if I used the access_ok appropriately inside my system call.

How to do this? I saw that, access_ok will fail if I pass kernel space pointer. But how do I write a driver program to do this?

Comment: just saw this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894359/how-to-make-system-call-from-another-system-call-in-kernel-space?rq=1). Is it possible that I can write another system call(say syscall2) and try to pass kernel pointer to my syscall1 and see if I have used the access_ok correctly or not in syscall1? I think system calls should not be used for this purpose. But out of curiosity, I wanted to know if this can render a simple test result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  you are trying to pass an invalid user space pointer to the macro **access_ok(type,addr,size);**.

so it just checks that the **provided pointer is not in kernel-space area** if it's in kernel-space memory then will return zero(0) else it will return true so in this way you can check your desired result.. And if you are providing any address outside kernel-memory may be accepted(**its possible that the provided address is not it the address-space of the process which is calling this system call in this case the type provided as VERIFY_READ or VERIFY_WRITE will decide what to do**).

From man page of access_ok() refer to http://mirror.linux.org.au/linux-mandocs/2.6.12.6/access_ok.html. **Note that, depending on architecture, this function probably just checks that the pointer is in the user space range - after calling this function, memory access functions may still return -EFAULT**

If you want to pass the pointer to the kernel then you can do it as
1-> define one structure which will contain pointer address.
2-> add the same structure in your kernel module or driver. So the kernel & user know about the structure.
3-> Add one parameter in your system call as `char __user var`.
4-> create one structure variable in your user space of the defined structure & pass it in the system call as you call in your user-space application.
5-> Inside kernel-module or driver where the code is defined for your system-call, create a structure variable of the same structure as you used in user-space. And now do what-ever you want.

`

```
struct new_struct
{
   void *p;  //set this pointer which you want to send...
};
    //from user-application...

    int main()
    {
       ....
       struct new_struct req_kernel;
       your_system_call_function(...,(void *)&req_kernel,...);
    }

    //this is inside your kernel...
         your_system_call(...,char __user optval,...)
         {
                .....
                struct new_struct req;
                if (copy_from_user(&req, optval, sizeof(req)))

                return -EFAULT;
                //now you have the address or pointer which you want in kernel with struct req...
        }
```

`

Comment: I knew what access_ok does before using it in a system call. But, my question is: how to write a user space program that passes an invalid pointer(pointer in kernel space) to my system call. Because, I want to see the access_ok() call returning EFAULT. In theory yes, I studied the man page and Robert Love's book. But, I want to see EFAULT getting thrown. So, how can I generate a kernel pointer in user space?

Comment: Vow, that was so elegant and nicely said. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @SaranyaDeviGanesan i have the same problem during first understanding this concept...