# How to verify if the pointer is pointing to the process address table

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I am trying to write my own system call under **Arch linux system**, the following is the format of the system call:

```
long getpeuid(pid_t pid, uid_t *uid)
```

Which is used to get the euid of calling process's parent process.

I know I have to verify three things first:

1. check if the pointer is pointing to the user space. **That can be done by `access_ok()`.**
2. check if the pointer is pointing to the calling process's address space.
3. check if the calling process has the permission to write to the space the pointer is pointing to.

I found the syscall `copy_to_user()` can copy the kernel space variable to user space, **but I am not sure if the syscall checks the other prerequisites first.**

Also, I am not sure how can I get the calling process's parent process euid. I know `getppid()` could get the parent process ID, but I am not sure how to proceed with that. Can someone give me some hint on this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

A follow up question, if I want to check if the effective uid of parent process is root, I could simply see if euid equals 0, is that right?

**EDIT:**

Another question, are we allowed to call getppid() and other syscalls inside a syscall? after some googling, it seems like everyone is trying to avoid doing this.

Comment: copy_to_user is not a syscall

Comment: @AlexHoppus, so what is the nature of `copy_to_user()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I'm new to Linux kernel development, please correct this answer as necessary!)*

Yes, `copy_to_user` makes all the needed checks to see if the process is allowed to write to the referenced memory space. That is a major reason why `copy_to_user` is used so often.

Once you have the PID of the parent process, you will need to get a reference to its task descriptor. I believe you can get that by calling `find_task_by_vpid(pid_number)`.

Now you have a pointer to the parent process' `task_struct`. It has 2 `struct cred *` members: `cred` and `real_cred`. (I'm not sure which one you should use.) `struct cred` has a member `euid`.

If the `euid` is 0, then yes, the parent process is running as root. Note that if the system uses LXC containers, then it could be root *inside* a container.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Another question, are we allowed to call `getppid()` and other syscalls inside a syscall? after some googling, it seems like everyone is trying to avoid doing this.

Comment: @JialunLiu, I'm not an expert and don't know about that. The definition of `getppid` is extremely simple: you can see it in `kernel/sys.c`. You could refer to it as a sample and do something similar in your own code if you like.

Comment: after playing around, I figured that it is not possible to call a syscall inside a syscall in kernel space, one can only use kernel functions to implement the syscall, more details could be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894359/how-to-make-system-call-from-another-system-call-in-kernel-space?rq=1

Comment: OK, I see. You should still be able to directly call `sys_getppid` if you want to -- that doesn't require making a syscall. I don't know if that is good style or not.

Comment: I am not sure about that, but going through the source code where linux defined its syscalls, I found all of them using kernel functions to implement syscall.